# Checking which item was select in CheckButtons

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image: Box selection]
Hi have a box with 3 selections. I'm trying to  know which item was select. Is there a way to find out which item was selected and remember? Because, I don't want the ability to be able to select 2 of the items at the same time. Can I check the boolean of each of the selections? I think it'd be easier to know if 'Mils/sec' was True or False..then I can switch it the opposite if another item was clicked.

Thanks

```
def func(label): # graph ax2
    global milse2a, milse4a, check
    if label == 'Distance (mils) Pk-Pk':
        if (milse2a == 0):
            milse2a = 1
            print(check.get_active())
            print(check.get())
            print(check.state()) #.state() didn't work
            #check.state(['selected'])
            #print(check.get_active(check.state()))
            #if label == 'Distance (m) Pk-Pk''
            #check = CheckButtons(rax, ('Mils/sec','Distance (mils) Pk-Pk', 'Distance (m) Pk-Pk'), (True, False, False))
            #CheckButt
            print('milse2a', milse2a)
        else:
            milse2a = 0
            print('milse2a', milse2a)
    if label == 'Distance (m) Pk-Pk':
        if (milse2b == 0):
            milse2b = 1
            print('milse2', milse4a)
        else:
            milse4a = 0
            print('milse2', milse4a)

rax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.62, 0.14, 0.045])
    check = CheckButtons(rax, ('Mils/sec','Distance (mils) Pk-Pk', 'Distance (m) Pk-Pk'), (False, False, False))
    enter code here
```

Comment: Matplotlib's current development version has a `get_status` method. This will be part of a stable release pretty soon. Until then, you may look at the duplicate's answers, especially my new answer to that question.